# Undo function not firing after keyup on textual input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a simple script showing the character count for a text input element or a textarea element.

```
$("input[type=text],textarea").keyup(function(){

    var currentLength = ($(this).val().length);
    var maximum = 100;  
    var spanLimit = $("span[name=Limit]");

    spanLimit.html("("+ currentLength + " of " + maximum + ")");
});
```

While the script performs its function, I noticed that the user loses the ability to undo his/her typing with either Ctrl+Z or the right click menu option.  If I comment out the following line, the undo function is not lost:

```
spanLimit.html("("+ currentLength + " of " + maximum + ")");
```

Is there any way to not lose the undo stack after performing DOM manipulation?

*P.S.  This behavior is visible when using IE8*

Comment: Prob. a copy/paste error but you're missing a double quote on this line `var spanLimit = $("span[name=Limit]);`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the typo.  I trimmed down some of the code to show only the root cause and forgot to terminate the quote.  Any thoughts on it now?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a quote in `var spanLimit = $("span[name=Limit]);`.

It should be `var spanLimit = $("span[name=Limit]");`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the typo. I trimmed down some of the code to show only the root cause and forgot to terminate the quote. Any thoughts on it now?